# How to make a TabularInline orderable by user?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I created an admin view using the TabularInline class. With this view it is not possible to let the user order/sort the table to their liking, like within a standard ModelAdmin view. I would like to achieve this. I am using Django 2.2.1.

### What I tried

- I searched the Django docs, but besides hard coding 'ordering' within the admin.py file, I couldn't find anything on this topic. This is not what I want, I want the admin user to choose how to order.
- I tried to use [adminsortable2](https://django-admin-sortable2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html), however I ran into some issues I couldn't resolve. This got me thinking: is it really not possible with the standard Django package.

### My code

My model consists of TimeFrames, which are made up by TimeSlots.
This is what my model.py looks like:

```
from django.db import models

class TimeFrame(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class TimeSlot(models.Model):
    DAY_CHOICES = ('work', 'Work'), ('weekend', 'Weekend')
    begin_time = models.TimeField()
    end_time = models.TimeField()
    reference = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
    day = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=DAY_CHOICES)
    timeframe = models.ForeignKey('TimeFrame', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I don't want to register a separate TimeSlot admin view, since the TimeSlots are always part of a TimeFrame. They don't exist on their own.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

class TimeSlotInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = TimeSlot
    ordering = ("day", "begin_time") #hard-coded ordering


@admin.register(TimeFrame)
class TimeFrameAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [TimeSlotInline]
```

### Expected outcome

Enable the admin user to sort like in a standard ModelAdmin view.

Comment: You can check this option too: https://github.com/incuna/django-orderable

Comment: django-admin-sortable2 should work with a TabularInline, it's actually well documented [here](https://django-admin-sortable2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#make-a-stacked-or-tabular-inline-view-sortable), so maybe try to reformulate your question showing what you did and which problems you encountered instead of saying  "I ran into some issues"

Comment: note that the principle behind manual sorting is that the model has **an additional field** storing the sort order (e.g. `order`). You can add that field yourself and let admins fill in the field manually. But packages like django-admin-sortable(2) and django-orderable take the complexity away by ensuring the order is updated for all rows when the sort-order is changed and by giving some drag-and-drop javascript functionality to set the `order`.

Comment: @dirkgroten, thanks, that second comment hinted me on my mistake. I didn't add 'ordering' to the Meta class of my class (in models.py). When I got this error initially, I thought it was referring to 'ordering' as part of my registering in admin.py. **So thanks!** However, It still don't get what I want. I just want the triangles on top of the columns which can be pressed to change the order.

Comment: drag-and-drop to change order doesn't work?

Comment: wait, the triangles on top of the columns have nothing to do with manually specifying an order. The django-admin-sortable enables users to set an order (which is also used by default as the ordering for the model), so that the default order is determined manually. But if you just want to sort in the admin by various columns, then adjust [`sortable_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.sortable_by) in the ModelAdmin. I guess the SortableAdmin mixin automatically removes the other fields (since it messes up manual ordering)

Comment: @dirkgroten, drag and drop does work. Adding the sortable to the ModelAdmin does not help. Not where I apply django-admin-sortable2, nor where i don't. I don't get any errors though.

Comment: we didn't understand your question. You don't want the user to be able to specify a sort **order** on the model, you just want the user to be able to specify the column by which to sort the view. Forget about django-sortable and the likes then.

Comment: I do want them to specify the sort order and to which column, by clicking on top, using the triangles. I don't care which columns, the admin user can click them all. Can't upload pics here, right?